# WS2812 Matrix colour problem. Power?

Tags: led, ws2812

I have 8 8x8 WS2812 Matrix LED boards connected together to make 2 16x16 matrices. I have them connected with Dupont wires.

I also power the 2 16x16 with Dupont wires that are connected to a 5v 60Amp PSU (More Leds will be added later). The PSU power  should easily support the LED power requirements however, if I set the brightness anything over 30...the first matrices start to get reddish at the end. They start white but as the end they are orange/red.  If I set the brightness to 20-25 they are white. So there must be something with the power but I have 60amps...Can it be that the Dupont cables are the bottleneck? The cables don't get hot...so I guess they are ok?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks 
V.A

Comment: Measure the voltage before and after the jumper wires.

Comment: If I have brightness 20, i get 4.6V at the last matrix...if I increase it to the max of 255, I get 2.6v at the last matrix...So you are right. Fore some reason a have a voltage drop although the matrices are designed to be interconnectable...with Vin and Vout on the board. Can you can think of any solution to this?

Comment: Some of the cheap jumpers I have are so small, they maybe have 7 tiny strands of copper. The voltage drop over them is significant enough that they aren't usable for transmitting power, only signal/data level.

Comment: I soldered some cables from an ATX power supply but have the same results...It only does it when using white as there are all three colours at max brightness. I am going to try some cable that is used in wall sockets...let's see.

Comment: Connect the power/gnd to both ends of the matrix  to relieve the current flow across the individual boards power traces.  May have to connect in the middle as well.

Comment: I tried that. It improves so that I can use 60 Brightness but anything over that causes issues. I will increase wire gauge and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Use at least AWG20 and power each possible spot on the matrices (in and out). All the energy not reaching the LEDs is fried in the DuPont wires. Use Ohms law.